# How to enable TaskO in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops

I installed the [TaskO](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SSGS.TaskO&ssr=false#overview) extension for my Azure DevOps organization. However, when I open one of my projects that uses the Scrum or Agile process I do not see where to create the automated tasks. Does anyone know how to create tasks with this extension?

Answer (score 0):

Following TaskO UI is shown for each project. You can add tasks to the project, edit and delete them. These work as templates for actual tasks which are created by Azure DevOps whenever you add requirement/user story/PBI. You can also see the button to add the tasks for existing requirements. This TaskO UI is not required to be used after you have defined the tasks for that project. Creation of the actual tasks works in the background.

Answer (score 0):

> How to enable TaskO in Azure DevOps

I am afraid this TaskO extension is not very compatible with Azure Devops. I have installed this extension successfully for a long time, but I still could not make it work for my Azure Devops.

After install that extension for my Azure DevOps account, I could not see any **add tasks UI** display on my Azure DevOps. And on the page [Q & A](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SSGS.TaskO&ssr=false#qna), there is also some feedback that they are not able to use this extension properly.

Besides, I have found a similar extension [TaskO 2015](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vs-publisher-14751.TaskO2015&ssr=false#overview), which is only work for TFS 2015. I am not very sure if this extension is work with Azure Deops. If this extension is work with Azure Devops, @Gouri S may need to provide us detailed instructions, which could help us to use this extension.

Hope this helps.